# How to implement algolia intantsearch pagination?

Tags: laravel, pagination, vue.js, algolia

Can anyone guide me please on how to add algolia instantsearch pagination? I have tried following code.. not worked :

**instantsearch.js**

```
var search = instantsearch({
  // Replace with your own values
  appId: 'myid',
  apiKey: 'mykey', // search only API key, no ADMIN key
  indexName: 'instant_search',
  urlSync: true
});

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
    container: '#pagination-container'
  })
);
```

**Html:**

```
<div id='pagination-container'></div>
```

**error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: instantsearch is not defined
    at instantsearch.js:1
```

Comment: You are passing `search.addWidget()` as the second parameter to `instantsearch`. That can't be right

Comment: i put it outside also but not working still.. can u please suggest me how to do this?? @thanksd

Comment: Can you update your question to include the updated code and also provide the error message you are getting?

Comment: @thanksd check the update and error please .. thanks

Comment: Your error means you never load `instantsearch`. Put `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>`

Comment: your cdn is not working; shows : "GET http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsear%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bch.min.js"

Comment: Works for me: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js

Comment: still shows these errors:

"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/instantsear%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bch.min.js 
127.0.0.1/:144 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Bmovie.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:167 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/instantsear%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bch.min.js 404 (Not Found)
autocomplete.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at autocomplete.js:22
(anonymous) @ autocomplete.js:22
pagination.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: instantsearch is not defined
    at pagination.js:1"

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyQENe?editors=1111

Comment: thanks for ur effort. but it may occur for some js conflict. so i pasted my whole code here : https://paste.laravel.io/WzGkq 
give it a look kindly.

Comment: ok its working now.. but new problem .. it shows the pagination but it doesn't bring the new page when click to 2,3 ... i have set hits per page to 20 . still it doesn't show anything when click the page number buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReferenceError: instantsearch is not defined` exception is thrown when the value of `instantsearch` is `undefined`. This means that at this point the value is not set.

As suggested by @thanksd this probably means that it the InstantSearch.js library is not yet loaded, when this script is executed. The easiest way to fix that is loading the library in the head of your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes its working now. but new problem .. it shows the pagination but it doesn't bring the new page when click to 2,3 ... i have set hits per page to 20 . still it doesn't show anything when click the page number buttons.. @bobylito

Comment: We should probably continue this discussion on support@algolia.com or on the community forum (https://discourse.algolia.com/) :)

Comment: here i created the issue : https://discourse.algolia.com/t/instantsearch-pagination-not-working-properly/1331?u=wahid.sherief123